# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »spionieren« und »nachspionieren«?

Tags: difference

Heute habe ich folgendes in einem Buch gelesen, und obwohl ich es verstehe, ich glaube, dass der Unterschied zu subtil für mich ist. Deshalb möchte ich wissen, was genau die beide bedeuten.

> Es war ein seltsames Gefühl, Mo nachzuspionieren.

Comment: Was sagen denn die Wörterbücher?

Comment: @userunknown: das Problem ist für den Anfragenden, dass es im Spanischen keinen Unterschied gibt.

Comment: @äüö Es gibt auch Wörterbücher in einer Sprache (dt. Wort, dt. Erklärung) und Wörterbücher in anderen Sprachen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### jemandem nachspionieren

> Claudia spioniert Robert nach.

Das heißt: Claudia beobachtet die Tätigkeiten von Robert und folgt seinen Spuren. Sie ist hinter ihm her, sie verfolgt ihn. Dabei führt Claudia ihre eigenen Tätigkeiten so aus, dass sie selbst unbemerkt bleibt. Insbesondere legt sie Wert darauf, dass Robert von ihrem Interesse an ihm nichts mitbekommt. Claudia sucht Orte auf, an denen Robert vor kurzem war.

Das Wort »nachspionieren« benötigt eine Ergänzung im Dativ. Diese Ergänzung gibt an, welche Person das Ziel der Beschattung ist.

> Wem spioniert Claudia nach?

---

### jemanden ausspionieren

> Günther spioniert seine Nachbarn aus.

Das ist sehr ähnlich wie nachspionieren, aber ohne, dass Günther seinen Zielpersonen folgt. Er beobachtet sie nur, und er sammelt aus anderen Quellen (z.B. Internet) Daten über die Personen, die er ausspioniert. Dabei kann Günther die ganze Zeit im eigenen Haus bleiben.

Auch »ausspionieren« verlangt eine Ergänzung, die das Ziel der Spionage angibt, diese Ergänzung muss aber im Akkusativ stehen.

> Wen spioniert Günther aus?

---

### an einem Ort herumspionieren

> Bernd spioniert in der Werkshalle herum.

Bernd betreibt Werksspionage. Er hat sich in die Werkshalle eines erfolgreichen Betriebes eingeschlichen und versucht herauszufinden, wie genau dort die Verkaufsschlager hergestellt werden. Mit »herumspionieren« ist gemeint, dass man einen Ort, an dem man eigentlich nichts zu suchen hat, genau inspiziert.

»Herumspionieren« braucht ebenfalls eine Ergänzung, nämlich eine, die einen Ort angibt.

> Wo spioniert Bernd herum?

In einigen andern Sprachen gibt es dafür einen eigenen Fall, den Lokativ, im Deutschen behilft man sich mit einer lokalen Präposition (in, an, auf, unter, ...), auf welche dann die Ergänzung dieser Präposition folgt, wobei die Präposition den grammatischen Fall ihrer eigenen Ergänzung bestimmt. (Das hat jetzt aber nichts mehr speziell mit *herumspionieren* zu tun, sondern gilt immer, wenn man nach einem Objekt mit »wo« fragen kann:

> Genitiv: Bernd spioniert innerhalb der Umzäunung herum.
>   Dativ: Bernd spioniert bei dem Abfalleimer herum.
>   Akkusativ: Bernd spioniert um den Ofen herum.

---

### spionieren

Das ist ein Begriff, der die Bedeutungen aller drei oben genannten Aktivitäten umfasst. Aus den obigen Sätzen kann man diese Aussage ableiten:

> Claudia, Günther und Bernd spionieren.

Das Verb »spionieren« benötigt außer dem Subjekt keine weitere Ergänzung. Das heißt aber nicht, dass man keine weiteren Ergänzungen anfügen dürfte. Sie sind nur nicht zwingend notwendig.

> Claudia spioniert am Dienstag.
>   Günther spioniert mit einem Fernrohr.
>   Bernd spioniert in einem Tarnanzug.

Answer (score 1):

um den Unterschied griffiger zu machen, muss man sich neben spionieren und nachspionieren, auch mal den Begriff ausspionieren anschauen.

Spionieren entspricht ja der geheimen Informationsbeschaffung. Nachspionieren ist gleichzusetzen mit hinterherspionieren. Bedeutet, wenn jemand etwas unternimmt, und du es in Erfahrung bringen willst, dann musst diesem *folgen* also ihm hinterher sein.

Ausspionieren tust du meistens Personen, Firmen oder Objekte, mit festen Informationen und du diese in Erfahrung bringen willst. Beispielsweise wenn du wissen willst, was ein Unternehmen gerade plant zu tun, dann spionierst du das Unternehmen aus.

Spionieren steht am Ende nie allein. *Ich spioniere ihn.* oder *Ich habe es spioniert.* In beiden Fällen muss ein *aus* oder *nach* noch vor oder an den Satz ran.

Ich hoffe ich konnte dir helfen.

Beste Grüße
GermanStefan

Comment: "Spionieren steht am Ende nie allein" - nö, ich kann einfach sagen "Ich spioniere.", ohne sonst etwas.

Comment: Hallo Stephie, ja stimmt schon, aber mir ging es darum, dass man die Information mitliefert, was man oder wem man aus-/hinterherspioniert. Einfach nur "Ich spioniere" ist nicht sehr informativ. Grüße

Answer (score 0):

spionieren = generell Informationen beschaffen

nachspionieren = hinterher spionieren = ausspionieren = speziell auf ein Objekt oder Subjekt gerichtet. Meist auch mit Bewegungsverfolgung.